# jquery addclass removeclass onclick on form labels

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, addclass, removeclass

i have a quite a simple addclass, removeclass function which i want to execute onclick, like so:

```
$('#filter').click(function() {
$(this).closest('fieldset').find('.selectedfilter').removeClass('selectedfilter');
$(this).parent().addClass('selectedfilter');
});​
```

david thomas provided a nice jsfiddle for exactly this:
http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eMx7X/

i have a form with the id 'filter' which contains (hidden) radio buttons and (visible) labels which are clickable. the active class is applied to the label which is checked on page load and should be changed to another label when clicked.

however, the jquery function does not work on this page: http://www.alexbrunner.com/travels/. not only does the addclass, removeclass not work, but also the [quicksand plugin](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/demos/one-set-clone.html) (which filters and sorts the items in the subsequent list just fine without the short .click-function) also stops working.

i am quite lost where the problem arises. i would very much appreciate any help on this!
the files are live at:

http://www.alexbrunner.com/travels/

http://www.alexbrunner.com/style.css (relevant lines in section 'quicksand shuffle')

Comment: is alert working inside the click function?

Comment: it doesn't seem to. can it be that i have to specify that the click is on the label and not on the radio buttons, since the buttons are hidden?

Comment: at least like this it doesn't:

`$('#filter').click(function() {
 alert("Alert");   $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.selectedfilter').removeClass('selectedfilter');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selectedfilter');
});​`

Comment: ok – thanks to rory the alert now works. there was an illegal character which i could not see in the editor. however, the addclass, removeclass still is not effective.

Comment: thank you @SreenathPlakkat and @Rory-McCrossan! unfortunately, still no solution on this one. if i change:

`$('#filter').click(function() {
$(this).closest('FIELDSET').find('.selectedfilter').removeClass('selectedfilter');
$(this).parent().addClass('selectedfilter');
});`

to:

`$('#filter').click(function() {
$(this).closest('#FILTER').find('.selectedfilter').removeClass('selectedfilter');
$(this).parent().addClass('selectedfilter');
});`

then the removeclass part works, but of course it is removed from BOTH fieldsets which is undesirable. the addclass still doesn't work. i'm quite puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Check the page in Firebug - you have a javascript error:

> illegal character
>   });​
>   ----^
>   /travels/ (line 279, col 3)

```
$('#filter').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.selectedfilter').removeClass('selectedfilter');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selectedfilter');
});â€‹
```

You can see the character at the end of the `click()` method.

Comment: thank you! that is a great hint. i could not see the character in my editor. it must have occurred through copying the lines back and fro. this solves the issue that the whole javascript functionality is now back (the quicksand shuffle). however, it does not solve the issue that the classes are not applied. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
   $("#filter").live("click", function () {
  $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.selectedfilter').removeClass('selectedfilter');
  $(this).parent().addClass('selectedfilter');
   });​
```

Comment: thank you! this works just as well – but not better. meaning the classes are still not applied.